# Pointer to Two Dimensional Structure Array

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a Structure say MyStruct:-

```
#define SEC_DIMENSION 2
struct MyStruct
{
  char cChar;
  float fFloat;
  int   iInt;
};

struct MyStruct StructArray[SEC_DIMENSION][20];  //Two Dimensional Array of Structures.
```

Now I want to access this with Pointer.

```
struct MyStruct *StructPtr[SEC_DIMENSION];
```

I did assignment as follows:-

```
 StructPtr[0] = &StructArray[0][0];
```

Now, I want to access Members of Structure StructArray[0][1] i.e. `StructArray[0][1].cChar` or `StructArray[0][1].fFloat`

How can I access them by using StructPtr?

I tried using `StuctPtr[0][1]->cChar` then `((StructPtr[0])[1])->cChar` 
Both returned an error.

With `StructPtr[0]->cChar` build was successful. But this is not what I want.

Comment: "But this is not what I want." , what do you want exactly ?

Comment: I want to Access StructArray[0][1].cChar using Pointers. In This case It would be accessing StructArray[0][0].cChar not for Other Members of This Array.

Comment: you have yourself assigned the address of the structure at array location `[0][0]` into the 0th element of the array of pointers StructPtr. Therefore `StructPtr[0]` now holds the structure `StructArray[0][0]` 's base address. Therefore `StructPtr[0]->cChar` will give you the `cChar` component of `StructArray[0][0]`

Comment: @Swanand Purankar: Huh? Why is it `StructArray[0][1]` in the first case, and then suddenly `StructArray[0][0]`? Sorry, this is all still overly confusing. Provide a better descripotion of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Now I want to access this with Pointer" is not very descriptive. What you have in your example will not work. What you declared is not a pointer to an array but rather an array of pointers. Is that what you need? I don't know.

If you really need a pointer to an array, you can declare your pointer it as

```
struct MyStruct (*StructPtr)[20];
```

and then make it point to your array as

```
StructPtr = StructArray;
```

From this point on you can access the original array through this pointer as `StructPtr[i][j]`

```
StructPtr[i][j].cChar = 'a';
```

Alternatively, you can declare the pointer as

```
struct MyStruct (*StructPtr)[SEC_DIMENSION][20];
```

and then make it point to your array as

```
StructPtr = &StructArray;
```

From this point on you can access the original array through this pointer as `(*StructPtr)[i][j]`

```
(*StructPtr)[i][j].cChar = 'a';
```

Comment: But struct MyStruct (*StructPtr)[SEC_DIMENSION][20] will declare (SEC_DIMENSION*20) pointers, Right? Instead of That 20, I want a Single Pointer with Which I could access All 20 structures and their members!

Comment: @Swanand Purankar: No. You need to get more familiar with C declarations first. `struct MyStruct (*StructPtr)[SEC_DIMENSION][20]` declares exactly **one** pointer. It will declare exactly **one** pointer that points to type `struct MyStruct[SEC_DIMENSION][20]`.

Comment: If you do `struct MyStruct *StructPtr[SEC_DIMENSION][20]`, then you'll get `SEC_DIMENSION*20` pointers. But one you add those extra parentheses, the meaning of the declaration changes drastically. How you get just one pointer.

Comment: Okey! Thanks! And Thanks for Clearing a Concept!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a "pointer to an array of dimension [SEC_DIMENSION][20] of structures of type struct MyStruct":

```
struct MyStruct (*StructPtr)[SEC_DIMENSION][20];

StructPtr = StructArray;

StructPtr[i][j]->cChar;
```